# assignment operators and c

Tags: c, assignment-operator

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int i,j;
   i=j=(22,23,24);
   printf("i:%d",i);
   printf("\nj:%d",j);
}
```

this is giving output of both i,j as 24.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int i,j;
   i=j=22,23,24;
   printf("i:%d",i);
   printf("\nj:%d",j);
}
```

and this gives both i,j as 22.
Can someone explain the terminlology behind.
TIA

Answer (score 5):

An assignment operator `=` has higher precedence than a comma operator `,`.

[C Operator Precedence - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

In this statement

```
i=j=(22,23,24);
```

`(22,23,24)` is firstly calculated. The `22` and `23` are ignored by the comma operator and it is evaluated to `24`. Then, the result `24` is assigned to `j`, and the value is also assigned to `i`.

On the other hand, in this statement

```
i=j=22,23,24;
```

`i=j=22` is firstly calculated. This assigns `22` to `j`, then assign the value to `i`. After that, the evaluation result of assignment operator `22`, and an integer literal `23` are ignored by the comma operator. Finally the expression is evaluated to the value `24`, which is also ignored.

Comment: FYI, be careful about “the value is also assigned to `i`” in other situations. In `x = y = value`, the `value` is not assigned to `y` and also assigned to `x`. `y` receives the value converted to the type of `y`, and then `x` receives the result of **that** converted to the type of `x`. So `double x; int y; x = y = 3.5;` assigns 3 to `x`, not 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

A comma separated list of *constant* expressions does not make much sense. The main purpose of comma operator is to separate *assignments* - a transparent and conscious side-effect.

With parentheses and two more assignments it groups as:

```
i = j = (22,x=23,y=24);
```

Since an expression in parens `(E)` is a primary expression, this can be hierarchically seen as

```
i = j = E;
```

This `E` consists of three comma separated (sub-)expressions where the last one counts. This is assignment `y=24` with result/evaluation `24`.

The `22` is thrown away, but `x=23` has the obvious side effect.

Normally `E` would be something like `2*n+1` that does not need parens. Until up to the `i = j > 22 ? 23 : 24` (where it gets a bit confusing).

The second one groups:

```
i=j=22, x=23, y=24;
```

This starts to make sense now. It is just three assigments on one line. 23 and 24 are not "lost".

---

The assigment expression `i=j=22` itself has one level of recursion; it works right-to-left, which is only natural.

But the examples are more about combining separating comma operators `,` and grouping parentheses `(` `)`.